# Use value from input field in js

Tags: jquery, html, store

I have a simple input html field. The value of this input field should be used in a jquery function later on.
How can I accomplish this? I think I have to either pass it directly to the function or store it - at least - temporary. Is there a way other than have it passed to my mySQL database and retrieve it?

Here's what I tried:

html:

```
Firstname: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
```

js:

```
var probe1 = $('#firstname').val();
```

... and then I thought about using the variable probe1 in my js script - Does not work.

The script I want to use the variable in is in another script tag.

Comment: if you remove var and make it probe1 = $('#firstname').val(); then probe1 will be global. However, global variables are bad and actually, $('#firstname').val() should work in any javascript file on the same page assuming they are in the same frame(not in a different iframe)

Comment: Take a look at the variable scope of javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope 

It might help clear things up.

Comment: We need to understand the scope of this variable. A good solution would be to save the value to a cookie or localStorage and refer to it in your function.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHardie, I dived into localStorage and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`var probe1` is probably just out of scope in your second script tag.

Simply redeclare the variable in the new script, or just use `$('#firstname').val()` in place of `probe1` in the second script.